# excel split string by different delimiters

Tags: excel, string, split

How would one split a cell containing string with different delimiters?

`Cell A2 has "14:5-18:24"`
into cells b2 to e2:
`14  5  18 24`

Comment: Do you want this in VBA?

Comment: both? in formula and vba, yeah that'd be nice.

Answer (score 1):

As a formula (requires Excel 365's Dynamic Array capability)

```
=IFERROR(TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-",":"),":","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b")),"")
```

As VBA

```vb
Sub Demo()
    Dim rSrc As Range
    Dim rDst As Range
    Dim Src As String
    Dim Result As Variant
    
    Set rSrc = ActiveSheet.Range("A2")
    Set rDst = ActiveSheet.Range("B2")
    Src = rSrc.Value2
    Result = Split(Replace$(rSrc.Value2, "-", ":"), ":")
    With rDst.Resize(1, UBound(Result) - LBound(Result) + 1)
        .Value2 = Result  ' Places result as strings
        .Value2 = .Value2 ' Convert to numbers
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this in Power Query:

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table9"]}[Content],
    Typed = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),

    Split = Table.SplitColumn(Typed,"Column1",Splitter.SplitTextByAnyDelimiter({":","-"}))
in
    Split
```

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.

[image]